Touchpad Right-Click on Debian
I am running Linux Mint Debian Edition on my Chromebook laptop. ChromeOS has an amazing feature where if you hold ALT, then click, a right click will register. I did some quick searches online and I was unable to find anything on enabling the feature in Debian. Any clues?

As usual, the two-finger tap should work.

Yes, but that does not fulfill my use case.

Your case is a non starter.

Your user case is to use ALT?

My request is to be able to hold ALT then click to register a right click in LMDE like ChromeOS does. Thank you!
